# Read video stream like on a web page like with VLC

Tags: jquery, video

I've subscribed to a streaming service, and I have a m3u file to open with VLC. This m3u file is a short playlist containing links for each video. If I enter a single link in VLC, I have the video instead of having my playlist. I've tried to embed a link in a HTML video tag, but after some searches I found that was not possible.

In order to play this stream source in a web page, I tried to identifiy the protocol used. The link is starting with HTTP. I tried to enter the link directly in my URL bar. A video player is showing, but nothings starts, while in VLC, it's working perfectly. I've tried `mediaelement`https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement but none of their supported format seemed to work. I don't really know how to identify the protocol of my stream and how to play it in a browser.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Use HLS.js ...,

Comment: This is not working, here is a link : http://cdnk.kcdn.tn/iptv/ch194?code=170311288566078

Comment: And? You just posted a link to a TS file. It's a video of a dude cooking. What is supposed to "work"?

Comment: This is not working with HLS.ts. I'd like to understand how to open it in a browser without VLC. How can I embed this video stream on my website ?

Comment: Browsers can't play TS files. hls.js can't either without an m3u8. VLC plays about 100 video formats. Web browsers play like 2. You need to convert the file into something a browser can play. like mp4. If you wish to play an his stream (with an m3u8 file, not just a ts file) than you can use his.js. There is no such thing has hls.ts,

Comment: So there is no way for me to play this stream on my browser ? No library exists for this ?